# Bitmap does not work in android version marshmallow and lollipop?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

When I have uses the below code this code is work up to android kitkat version but its not work in lollipop and marshmallow version. when I pick an image it does not show in imageview and throw an exception in lollipop and marshmallow.

Here I attached my code for displaying an image from gallery on button click.

```
FloatingActionButton pick = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pick);
    pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);

            }
    });
    @Override
    protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };


            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString,options);
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            int height = bitmap.getHeight() * 4, width = bitmap.getWidth() * 4;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Height" + height + "Width" + width, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (height > 4096 || width > 4096){
                bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString,options);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need to Resize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace code of the exception.

Comment: possible reported issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175157

Comment: I have found that all above kitkat versions the code for pick image from gallery is different.